# How to move a GTK3 widget inside a Fixed container with Python?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, gtk

I want to implement a drag-and-drop like moving behavior of a widget inside a Fixed. I already placed the widget at some arbitrary location on the Fixed, and made the cursor reflect hovering/dragging events. I also used an EventBox around the widget, but this does not matter here.

With my current OOP/Template code structure, i need to do the following:

1. add a signal to the widget, that i want to move (which ones? `button-press-event`, `button-release-event`, `motion-notify-event`)
2. get the Fixed Container from the Widget (somewhat like getting its parent)
3. get the position of the widget inside the fixed
4. when the button is pressed move the widget with the cursor on the Fixed (or maybe only attach a "ghost-outline" to the cursor and when placed down move the actual widget)

Do you have code snippets, that manage some steps of this? Thanks!

Comment: I found this older code, which is written in python2: https://gist.github.com/KurtJacobson/57679e5036dc78e6a7a3ba5e0155dad1#file-drag-py